# Changing Screen from another Layout

Tags: python, kivy

My intent is to have a layout to the right of our window and a ScreenManager to the right. Both are in different layouts, but in the same main app. I seem not to be able to have a button on a layout change screen on the Screen Manager.

This is my kv code:

```
<MainWindow>:
    rows: 1
    columns: 2

    LeftBox:

    RightBox:

<LeftBox>:
    Button:
        text: "Screen 1"
        on_press:
            app.root.ids.scr.switch_to(screen=Screen1)

    Button:
        text: "Screen 2"

<RightBox>:
    ScrMng:

<ScrMng>:
    id: scr

    Screen1:
        Button:
            text: "Hello"

    Screen2:
        Button:
            text: "World"
```

And this is my python code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class MainWindow(GridLayout):
    pass

class ScrMng(ScreenManager):
    pass

class LeftBox(BoxLayout):
    pass

class RightBox(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class newtestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()

k = newtestApp()
k.run()
```

The error I get is

> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '`__getattr__`'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem - KeyError

Before the `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'` there is a `KeyError: 'scr'`

```
app.root.ids.scr.switch_to(screen=Screen1)
```

## Solution

1. Add `id: rbox` for instantiated `RightBox:` widget in class rule, `<MainWindow>:` so that we can access `id: scr` using `ids.rbox.ids.scr`
2. Move `id: scr` from class rule, `<ScrMng>:` to after instantiated `ScrMng:` in class rule, `<RightBox>:`
3. Add `name: 'screen1'` and `name: 'screen2'` to instantiated `Screen1:` and `Screen2:` respectively.
4. Replace `app.root.ids.scr.switch_to(screen=Screen1)` with `app.root.ids.rbox.ids.scr.current = 'screen1'`

[ScreenManager: current vs switch_to](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#advanced-usage)

> **Note** that this method adds the screen to the [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager) instance and should not be used if your screens have already been
>   added to this instance. To switch to a screen which is already added,
>   you should use the [current](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.current) property.

[ScreenManager » switch_to](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.switch_to)

> ```
> switch_to(screen, **options)
> ```
>
> Add a new screen to the ScreenManager and switch to it. The previous
>   screen will be removed from the children. options are the transition
>   options that will be changed before the animation happens.

## kv file

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<MainWindow>:
    rows: 1
    columns: 2

    LeftBox:

    RightBox:
        id: rbox

<LeftBox>:
    Button:
        text: "Screen 1"
        on_press:
            app.root.ids.rbox.ids.scr.current = 'screen1'

    Button:
        text: "Screen 2"
        on_press:
            app.root.ids.rbox.ids.scr.current = 'screen2'

<RightBox>:
    ScrMng:
        id: scr

<ScrMng>:

    Screen1:
        name: 'screen1'
        Button:
            text: "Hello"

    Screen2:
        name: 'screen2'
        Button:
            text: "World"
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]

Comment: One note that might also help clarify the situation. From [Kv Language Documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html):  `An id is limited in scope to the rule it is declared in`. Explains why the `ids.rbox.ids` chaining must be used.